# Writing a systemd script that starts 2 applications in linux

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, systemd, raspbian

OS: Raspbian

I'm failing to execute 2 applications at once with `rc.local`

I need to find a simple example for how to start an app with systemd

The problem is Im only finding specific examples for starting servers and they are very complex, I have a hard time understanding how to write a simple systemd file that executes an application, where to place it, and how to get it started.

The two apps Im tryign to execute are : `/home/pi/app1` and `/home/pi/app2`

When I run a command line like this: both apps run concurrently

`/home/pi/app1 & /home/pi/app2 &`

But for some reason, when I put the same line into rc.local, only the first app runs,

I also cannot seem to dump data from rc.local

`/home/pi/app1 & /home/pi/app2 &> /tmp/log`  that /tmp/log file never gets created

I dont understand why this doesn't work, I was suggested to use systemd but it so unnecessarily complicated with too many options.

What would a simple systemd file to execute one of these apps look like?

I just want something reliable that will start these two apps on boot, thats all

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proponents of systemd will tell you that systemd is easier because you don't need to write scripts.

For systemd, you will probably need two services, one for `app1` and one for `app2`. Create the files in `/etc/systemd/system`, for example `app1.service` with:

```
[Unit]
Description=app1 systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/of/your/app/app1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable at boot time do

```
systemctl enable app1.service
```

Comment: Thanks,What is easier to use? And most reliable? This did not work, it started the first, but failed to start the second app