# Cannot get systemd to restart a service if it crashes

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, systemd

I searched online and posted here to understand how to use systemd to auto start a c++ application, now I want it to automatically restart that application if it crashes.

I know the correct course of action is to make the application not crash, but it is not my program to change

Here is what I gathered so far from here:

https://singlebrook.com/2017/10/23/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/

and here:
[Writing a systemd script that starts 2 applications in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1521840/writing-a-systemd-script-that-starts-2-applications-in-linux)

Create the file in `/etc/systemd/system/app1.service` with:

```
[Unit]
Description=app1 systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/app1
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then execute to enable service

`sudo systemctl enable app1.service`

The service starts up initially, but when I execute

`sudo kill xx` where xx is the pid of the app, it does not restart itself

How can I fix this `init.d` script to automatically restart the app if it crashes?

Or is it not going to work if I kill it though `sudo kill`? In this case how can I test that it works without waiting for it to crash?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `Restart=on-failure` does [emphasis mine]:

> `Restart=`
>
> Configures whether the service shall be restarted when the service process exits, is killed, or a timeout is reached. […]
>
> Takes one of `no`, `on-success`, `on-failure`, `on-abnormal`, `on-watchdog`, `on-abort`, or `always`. […] In this context, a clean exit means an exit code of `0`, or one of the signals `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` or `SIGPIPE`, and additionally, exit statuses and signals specified in `SuccessExitStatus=`. If set to `on-failure`, the service will be restarted when the process exits with a non-zero exit code, is terminated by a signal (including on core dump, but **excluding the aforementioned four signals**), when an operation (such as service reload) times out, and when the configured watchdog timeout is triggered.

<sup>([source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=))</sup>

`kill` sends `SIGTERM` by default. That's why the service does not restart itself after you kill it.

> How can I fix this script to automatically restart the app if it crashes?

If the app returns non-zero exit status in such situation then there's nothing to fix. The service will be restarted.

> how can I test that it works without waiting for it to crash?

1. Kill it with [`SIGQUIT` or `SIGKILL`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251267/108618):

   ```
   kill -s SIGQUIT $pid
   ```
2. Or you can use `RestartForceExitStatus=SIGTERM` to make the service restart itself after `SIGTERM`. But note `kill $pid` will then test if `RestartForceExitStatus=` works, not exactly `Restart=`.
3. Or you can (temporarily) modify `/home/pi/app1` so it exits with a non-zero exit status after receiving `SIGUSR1` or after few seconds. Send `SIGUSR1` to the process or just wait, then poll `systemctl status app1.service` to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, you can check my answer above too, it needed the forking type and the pidfile, but it actually worked with the sudo kill command after

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix

It needed the forking type and the pid file, 
this will work with the `sudo kill` command
Thanks,

```
[Unit]
Description=app1 systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/fbcp-ili9341
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: One should use `forking` if the application forks, not as an ad-hoc fix. It really depends on what `app1` (or `fbcp-ili9341`) does, the question does not specify. Even if `Type=forking` seems to help, you should choose the right `Type=` first, then debug within the type. Choosing the wrong type may make the service misbehave later. To make this answer useful for other users you should explain why `forking` is right in your case an what difference it makes when you `kill`. Frankly, I tested your code with application that really forks and `SIGTERM` still doesn't trigger `Restart=on-failure`.

Comment: Im, not an expert on system service, so I'll just change the code again, feel free to edit my answer