# linux- systemd service: If the service fails once try to restart it with a limited number of retries

Tags: systemd

How can I configure systemd to try to restart a service until a limit of restart is reached.

I have a script that crashes a lot of time and each time that happens I want to restart it. But with a few limitations:

The service should have a delay of 3 seconds before each restart
The service should only retry to start the script 3 times then it should require manual restart.

I think I already found out how to make it restart on failure with a delay of 3 seconds using `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=3` but I have no idea how to do the limit restart. I've found about `StartLimitIntervalSec` and `StartLimitBurst` but I have no idea how to use it. Will these get applied when the service starts or only on restarts, also how to use them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get systemd to restart a service if it crashes](https://superuser.com/questions/1530033/cannot-get-systemd-to-restart-a-service-if-it-crashes)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work for you:

```
[Unit]
StartLimitIntervalSec=10
[Service]
StartLimitBurst=3
```

1. RestartLimitBurst defines how many times to retry
2. `StartLimitIntervalSec` > `StartLimitBurst`*`RestartSec`
3. `StartLimitIntervalSec` has been moved to `[Unit]` since 2018, according to [Systemd unit incorrect config](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/10065), which is different from document below.

If the number of reboots `RestartLimitBurst` in `RestartLimitIntervalSec`, the systemd will stop to retart.

Below is what i find in the document: [systemd.unit — Unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

> StartLimitIntervalSec=interval, StartLimitBurst=burst
> Configure unit start rate limiting. Units which are started more than burst times within an interval time span are not permitted to start any more. Use StartLimitIntervalSec= to configure the checking interval and StartLimitBurst= to configure how many starts per interval are allowed.
>
> interval is a time span with the default unit of seconds, but other units may be specified, see systemd.time(5). Defaults to DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec= in manager configuration file, and may be set to 0 to disable any kind of rate limiting. burst is a number and defaults to DefaultStartLimitBurst= in manager configuration file.